# AWS DynamoDB getItem getting item by username not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to retrieve a database item with the username key of my DB.
I have the following PHP code:

```
$result = $DBclient->getItem(array(
        "TableName" => $TableName,
        "ConsistentRead" => true,
        "Key" => array(
            "username" => strtolower($_POST["username"])
        )
    ));
```

After it runs, the following error occurs:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException: AWS Error Code: SerializationException, Status Code: 400, AWS Request ID: (...), AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: Expected null, User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.8.31 Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.51.0 PHP/5.6.30 thrown in (...)\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\Common\Exception\NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on line 91
```

My table has three keys (indexes, rows...) : username (S), password (S), and id (N)

I read the documentation but i think i'm missing something here.

Comment: What is the partition key of your table ? what do you mean by three keys? Please provide the key definition of your table?

Comment: The "Key" parameter in the call to `getItem()` needs to be a reference to the DynamoDb table's primary key in its entirety. That means the partition key and also the sort key, if you have one assigned. If 'username' is not the primary key then you probably want to use the `Scan()` method instead of `getItem()`.

Comment: @notionquest My primary key is ***username*** and its secondary key is ***password***. The secondary indexes are ***email*** and ***id***.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the type of your `Key` element and the value. You are missing the type.

So your code should be:

```
$result = $DBclient->getItem(array(
        "TableName" => $TableName,
        "ConsistentRead" => true,
        "Key" => array(
            "username" => array("S" => strtolower($_POST["username"]))
        )
    ));
```

Comment: I changed it and now it tells me that ***The provided key element does not match the schema***

Comment: @shanidahan Does your table have username key as a string?